# Shortcut for switching keyboard layouts without cycling through all options

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 with multiple keyboard layouts.

I would like to have a keyboard shortcut for each of the keyboard layouts I am using to directly enable it, without cycling through all the choices. Is there such a possibility?